# How do I start a UWP Emulator?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, uwp

I have created a cross platform app (Xamarin), which is targeted by UWP.  It just uses the default template and that is it.  I am now trying to debug it using an emulator, however the only debugging option I have is: "Device", which means I have to plugin a Windows phone.

I have also gone here and installed an emulator ( Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (version 1709 - this is what my app targets): https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive.  After installing; I ran: C:\Users\MyUserAccount\Downloads\Windows Kits\10\Emulator\EmulatorSetup.exe and I see the message: The features installed on this computer are now up to date.

However, I still see no Emulator to start in the debugging menu.

Basically I am trying to do the UWP equivalent of Androids: Tools/Android/Android Device Menu/Start (start is an option for each emulator).

How do I start a UWP Emulator? The Tools menu in Visual Studio 2017 has an Android Device Manager and a IOS Device Manager, but no UWP Device Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I start a UWP Emulator?

After installed emulator(10.0.15254.1), you need modify the app's min version to 15063. this lowest support version.

[image]

And your system need to support **Hardware-assisted virtualization** and
[image]

**Enable Hyper-v for emulator**

[image]

Then switch the **Solution Platforms** to X86 or x64.

[image]

For more info please refer [**Test with the Microsoft Emulator for Windows 10 Mobile**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/test-with-the-emulator)

Comment: Thanks.  Is it not possible to test with an emulator when using .net standard for the xamarin project?

Comment: .net standard support   the lowest version is 16299, so we can't run it within emulator any more

Comment: Could you have a look at my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58096724/tabs-are-missing-from-my-uwp-app-that-targets-xamarin ?

Comment: I saw our team member has replied your case, please pay attention to the following updaye.