# Tabs are missing from my UWP app that targets Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, uwp

I have created a simple Xamarin application, which contains two pages and each page is accessed by tabbing as shown below:

[image]

The Android target is working correctly (shown in the screenshot above) so I have now added a UWP target.  The problem is that the UWP target only displays one page i.e. there is no tab, so no way to tab between the two pages.

How can I add the tabs to the UWP app?  Note that I used a tab template when I created the UWP app.

Everything else works as expected (except the tabs).

I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Here is the XAML of the main page:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem
    Command="{Binding SettingsCommand}"
    Text="Settings">
        <ToolbarItem.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="app_settings" />
                <On Platform="UWP, WinRT, WinPhone" Value="Assets/app_settings.png" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

<TabbedPage.Title>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
        <On Platform="iOS, UWP, WinRT, WinPhone" Value="MyNamespace" />
    </OnPlatform>
</TabbedPage.Title>

<views:TestEnquiriesView
  x:Name="TestView">
    <views:TestEnquiriesView.Title>Test</views:TestEnquiriesView.Title>
</views:TestEnquiriesView>

<views:ProfileView
  x:Name="ProfileView">
    <views:ProfileView.Icon>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
            <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="menu_profile" />
            <On Platform="UWP, WinRT, WinPhone" Value="Assets\menu_profile.png" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </views:ProfileView.Icon>
</views:ProfileView>
```

Comment: I cannot make out what you are trying to show with the picture. Can you please post your XAML?

Comment: @Mindweep, I have added the XAML.  Please take a look.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Did you set the Title property for ContentPage? If so, can you provide the full `TabbedPage` code?

Comment: @Richard Zhanf, could you clarify what you mean (perhaps wit a hyperlink?).  It works properly on android.  Thanks.

Comment: Here is the [TabbedPage document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page#overview). I didn't see your complete code, but from the picture you provided, you created the icon for the tab, which does not appear as the title of the tab on the UWP. So I want to know if you set the `Title` property for the child elements of `TabbedPage`, which will be recognized as the display name of the tab.

Comment: @Richarx Zhang, is this specific to uwp? I will check when I return to my desk shortly.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, UWP is not quite the same as Android and IOS. These are also explained in the documentation. You can choose to set the `Title` property separately in the UWP platform.

Comment: @Richard Zhang, so you must set the title for the tabs to appear specifically for UWP? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is the recommended practice

Comment: @Richard Zhang, adding a title has fixed the issue.  If you would like to add an answer then please do.

Comment: @w0051977 Thank you for your support, I have compiled the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a Title property on a child element of `TabbedPage`. In UWP, `TabbedPage` recognizes the `Title` property of the child element and uses it as the display text of the tab.

This behavior is different from Android. Icons set in Android cannot appear as display text in UWP.

Here is the [TabbedPage document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page#overview).

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks +1 for the 'title' explanation.  Before I accept - are you saying that you cannot put an icon as a title in  UWP?

Comment: Sorry, this is what I did not expressly. In Android, you can use icons instead of setting a Title. But in UWP you need the Title property. Of course, UWP can use icons, but not `AppCompat`, but you need to create font icons yourself.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by AppCompat? I am new to UWP.  Thanks.

Comment: `AppCompat` is the content of Android, not UWP. You can find relevant content online. I don't know if you use `AppCompat`, because I can see the icons displayed on your tab, so there is this guess.